# How to auto generate a diagram out of my AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, images, aws-vpc, architecture

Does AWS provide a tool to visualize my VPC?

I would like to generate an image file with all services (shown as icons) provisioned inside a VPC.

Tools like draw.io and others are available. But doesnt AWS provide a cloud native tool for this?

Answer (score 7):

Yes and it costs 400$ a month.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/aws-perspective/welcome.html

It's a live diagram of all the resource in your organization, which means that it's capable of generating a live diagram for several accounts.

Seems crazy, but this can actually be useful to get a birdseye view of all the resources in complex scenarios.
Also, nothing is keeping you from starting this service, letting it run for an hour, getting a screenshot and shutting it all down.

If that is not good enough, lucid chart and cloudcraft are two good alternatives from trustworthy companies.
Be very careful when granting read access to your accounts.

https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/aws-architecture-import

https://www.cloudcraft.co/